# ASP.NET MVC RedirectToAction QueryString

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am on a view where the user modifies the page where the url is as follows:

```
    http://localhost:45217/DView/EditResultsDetail?locId=3397&paramId=1375&Date=02%2F11%2F2013%2014%3A44%3A47
```

When the user clicks on Submit, I do a POST. I do a RedirectToAction follows:

```
     return RedirectToAction("ResultsDetail", new { locId = locId, dt = date });
```

This works in that the ResultsDetail action is called and corret view is displayed.

The problem though is the the querystring still remains:

```
                http://localhost:45217/DView/EditResultsDetail?locId=3397&paramId=1375&Date=02%2F11%2F2013%2014%3A44%3A47
```

The problem with this is that if the user clicks on Refresh, they will go back to the EditResultsDetail action and not remain on ResultsDetail.

Comment: That would not happen. A `RedirectToAction` sends a redirect code back to the browser, so it would do a full redirect to your new URL. The only time I'd expect to see this problem is if you were inside of an `iframe`. Make sure that `RedirectToAction` code is actually happening, and keep an eye on the HTTP calls in Fiddler or your browser's network tab.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I am using this with Jquery Mobile so not sure if this may an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your form submission is not doing a full post, but rather an AJAX call. jQueryMobile is probably doing that automatically for you.

I believe putting `data-ajax="false"` inside your form tag will prevent the AJAX call and do a full post instead. This will take away some of the niceness of jQueryMobile's user experience, but it should get you what you're asking for.